# Multi-site, multiple database and 1 shared database

Tags: multi-sites, database

I want to develop drupal multi-site with this structure:

- One shared codebase drupal 7 multi-site, each web site has own database.
- One master web site that has some tables shared.
- Each multi site instances read some tables from master's database, not own database. For example conntent types, fields, views, rules and related configirations read only master's database. So I can develop all sites on one place.

As a result each site must use same content types, views, rules but different contents. I am user 1 of all sites. Sub site editors has create content and user permisions only. I dont want to share users accross sites. So I cant use domain acceess. Is it possible that?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your need is

> each site must use same content types, views, rules but different contents

[Domain Access](https://drupal.org/project/domain) is simplest answer:

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites such as:
>
> - example.com
> - one.example.com
> - two.example.com
> - my.example.com
> - thisexample.com <-- can use any domain string
> - example.com:3000 <-- treats non-standard ports as unique

Of course it uses one database, but end-user experience you need is covered.

Comment: Thanks molot. I try Domain Access but my clients needs isolated each others. It is possible to isolated users and contents like seperate database? I use user reference module.

Answer (score 0):

Use Features module to store your content types, views, rules etc. in code as custom modules and enable those modules on each site in your multi-site install.

This way all sites have the same config but separate databases and you don't need a "master" database.